# Does ${\rm tr}(\Pi_z\rho\Pi_z)\le p$ imply $\cal E(\rho)$ and $\cal E(\Pi_{-z}\rho\Pi_{-z})$ are close in trace distance?

Tags: quantum-operation, information-theory, trace-distance, projection-operator

Suppose I have a quantum operation $\mathcal{E}$ and a state $\rho$ such that:

$$ \operatorname{tr}(\Pi_z \rho \Pi_z) \le p $$

for some probability $p$ and some projection $\Pi_z$ onto some subspace of the Hilbert space. Let $\Pi_{-z} = \mathbb{1} - \Pi_z$.

I would like to prove (or disprove) that $\mathcal{E}(\rho)$ and $\mathcal{E}(\Pi_{-z} \rho \Pi_{-z})$ are close to each other, i.e. finding a bound for:

$$ || \mathcal{E}(\rho) - \mathcal{E}(\Pi_{-z} \rho \Pi_{-z}) ||_1 $$

The first thing it comes natural to do is to apply contractivity of quantum channels:

$$ || \mathcal{E}(\rho) - \mathcal{E}(\Pi_{-z} \rho \Pi_{-z}) ||_1 \le || \rho - \Pi_{-z} \rho \Pi_{-z} ||_1 $$

But now I can't go ahead. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Using the triangle inequality, we have
$$||\rho-\Pi_{-z}\rho\Pi_{-z}||_1\leq ||\rho||_1+||\Pi_{-z}\rho\Pi_{-z}||_1=1+\mathrm{Tr}(\Pi_{-z}\rho\Pi_{-z})$$ (the final equality holds because $\rho$ and $\Pi_{-z}\rho\Pi_{-z}$ are positive semidefinite). Then we can use $\Pi_{z}^2=\Pi_{z}$ and cyclicity of the trace to find
$$\mathrm{Tr}(\Pi_{-z}\rho\Pi_{-z})=\mathrm{Tr}(\rho+\Pi_{z}\rho\Pi_{z}-\Pi_{z}\rho-\rho\Pi_{z})=\mathrm{Tr}(\rho-\Pi_{z}\rho\Pi_{z})=1-p.$$ Overall we thus have
$$||\mathcal{E}(\rho)-\mathcal{E}(\Pi_{-z}\rho\Pi_{-z})||_1\leq 2-p.$$

Comment: isn't the first one $2 - p$?

Comment: @NoImaginationGuy for sure, edited, thanks!

Comment: The second equality is not correct. Consider $\rho = \begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta \\ \beta^* & 1-\alpha \end{pmatrix}$ and $\Pi_z = |0\rangle \langle 0|$. Then the LHS gives $\sqrt{\alpha^2 + |\beta|^2}$ but the RHS gives $\alpha$, These are clearly not the same when $beta \neq 0$.

Comment: Great, thanks @Rammus. So we are stuck with the first answer